# Missing GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.nib

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm new to IOS application development.

In my presently working application we have feature where user can upload his files to Google Drive for which I have integrated Google Drive SDK in my project.

So,for differentiation between iPhone and iPad xib file i'm maintaining `GTMOAuth2ViewTouch~iphone.xib` for iphone and `GTMOAuth2ViewTouch~ipad.xib` for iPad. It's working fine for iPad but in iPhone it is giving me `missing GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.nib` error in the log. What is the mistake am i doing here?